# Need guidance on how to populate a DIV using server side Ajax query then iterate with @foreach. Currently getting 'undefined variable' error

Tags: ajax, laravel

In a Laravel project I'm attempting to use Ajax to populate a DIV and then use @foreach to populate the store gallery.  If possible I wanted to use a Server side content generation strategy.  However, something silly is going on that I can't figure out-- I'm getting the following error:

```
$user_query is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $user_query }} with {{ $user_query ?? '' }}
```

How is this (@foreach ($user_query as $item)) suppose to be constructed in the blade?

**routes**

```
    Route::get('/ajaxStoreRequest', 'StoreController@ajaxStoreRequest');
    Route::post('/ajaxStoreRequest/post', 'StoreController@ajaxStoreRequestPost');
```

**Here is the StoreController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Coin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DataTables\StoresDataTable;
use App\DataTables\StoresDataTableEditor;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class StoreController extends Controller
{
    public function ajaxStoreRequest()
    {
        return view('store.index');
    }

    public function ajaxStoreRequestPost(Request $request)
    {
        $user_query= DB::table('coins')
            ->select('id','year', 'mint', 'series', 'rating', 'rating_group','photo_link1', 'for_sale_price')
            ->where('for_sale', '=', 1)
            ->where('sold', '=', 0)
            ->where('series', '=', $request->series)
            ->where('year', '=', $request->year)
            ->where('mint', '=', $request->mint)
            ->where('rating_group', '=', $request->rating_group)
            ->get();

        return response()->json($user_query);
    }

}
```

**a DD($user_query); shows the following array format**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#552
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => {#555
      +"id": 2
      +"year": 1878
      +"mint": "Philadelphia"
      +"series": "Morgan Dollar"
      +"rating": "Ungraded"
      +"rating_group": "PCGS"
      +"photo_link1": "editor/20200328_002220_888888966_732020162248388.jpg"
      +"for_sale_price": "44"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here is the Ajax script from the bottom of the store/index.blade.php**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, type) {
                if (!type.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
                }
            },
        });

        $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var series = $("#series option:selected").val();
            var year = $("input[name=year]").val();
            var mint = $("#mint option:selected").val();
            var rating_group = $("#rating_group option:selected").val();
            var price_filter = $("input[name=price_filter]:checked").val();

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/ajaxStoreRequest/post',
                data:{series:series, year:year, mint:mint, rating_group:rating_group, price_filter:price_filter},
                success:function(result){
                    $('.collapse').collapse('show');
                    $('#user_query').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Here is the HTML further up in the store/index.blade.php**

```
<div class="row row-deck js-gallery collapse">
    <div class="user_query" id="user_query">
    @foreach ($user_query as $item)                                  <!-- THIS IS THE ERROR -->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
            <div class="block">
                <div class="options-container">
                    @if ($item->photo_link1)
                        <img class="img-fluid options-item" src="storage/{{$item->photo_link1}}" style="width:300px; height:300px" alt="">
                    @else
                        <img class="img-fluid options-item" src="images/no-user-profile-picture-1200x900.jpg" style="width:300px; height:300px" alt="">
                    @endif
                    <div class="options-overlay bg-black-75">
                        <div class="options-overlay-content">                       
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary img-lightbox" href="gallery/{{$item->id}}">
                                View
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-light" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus text-success mr-1"></i> Add to cart
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content">
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <div class="h4 font-w600 text-success float-right ml-1">${{$item->for_sale_price}}</div>
                        <a class="h4" href="be_pages_ecom_store_product.html">{{$item->year}}-{{$item->mint}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="font-size-sm text-muted">{{$item->series}} ({{$item->rating}} {{$item->rating_group}})</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm attempting to use Ajax to populate a DIV and then use @foreach

This is fundamentally backwards. `store/index.blade.php` is rendered server side, so any data returned from your ajax call must be added to the DOM using JavaScript.

Comment: I was afraid of that... I was following option #1 here: https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/51387/reload-laravel-foreach-after-ajax .   I'll try to redesign building the div out in JS as in option 2.

Comment: just so i understand.  I need to do something like this correct: `success:function(result){
                    $('.collapse').collapse('show');

                    var appendString = "";
                    for(var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++){
                        appendString += "<div class=\"col-md-6 col-xl-4\">
                            <div class=\"block\">
                                <div class=\"options-container\">
                                    @if (" + result[i].photo_link1 + ")  `

Comment: sorry for that format mess. doesn't seem like markdown works well in comments.  basically asking if option 2 in that link is the way to go.

Comment: @scottsuhy Yeah you're on the right track there. Just build up the HTML programatically in JS.

Comment: For anyone that reviews this thread in the future check out pagination and the architecture required (here is an example: https://www.webslesson.info/2018/09/laravel-pagination-using-ajax.html)  In the end this is how I needed to redesign the code (using 2 views vs. 1) and not building the div out in the JS.